# Simple tikz-cd triangle: how add upward arrow

Tags: tikz-cd

How can I get an arrow going vertically upward, from Z to Y, like what I drew by hand in red, in the following diagram?

[image: triangle missing right side's up arrow]

Code so far:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \begin{document}
  
  \begin{tikzcd}
    & Y 
  \\
  X \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q}&
  \\
    & Z
  \end{tikzcd}
  
  \end{document}
```

The issue is that the arrow must span from the bottom, 3rd, row to the top, 1st row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go up two rows using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  & Y \\
X \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q}&\\
  & Z \arrow{uu}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Or you can explicitly specify the target cell, e.g. `1-2` for 1st row, 2nd column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  & Y \\
X \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q}&\\
  & Z \arrow{1-2}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, `tikz-cd` allows for a much better way to input arrows, with a key-value based method. For instance, your arrows are

```
\arrow[ur,"f"]
\arrow[dr,"g"']
```

The apostrophe can also be replaced by the key `swap` as in

```
\arrow[dr,"g" swap]
```

This is much clearer and more forgiving, as you don't need to remember the order of mandatory and optional arguments in the older `\arrow` syntax.

I recommend to put first the “target” specifier: `u` is for up, `d` for down, `l` for left and `r` for right. You can combine them as you like and you can jump over columns or rows by doubling (or tripling or …) the specifier. Thus you want

```
Z \arrow[uu]
```

that will do two steps up.

I also add two “horizontal” versions of the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  & Y \\
X \arrow[ur,"f"] \arrow[dr,"q"'] \\
  & Z \arrow[uu]
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}
  & Y \\
X \arrow[ur,"f"] \arrow[dr,"q" swap] \\
  & Z \arrow[uu]
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}
& X \arrow[dl,"q" swap] \arrow[dr,"f"] \\
Z \arrow[rr] && Y
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}
& X \arrow[dl,"f" swap] \arrow[dr,"q"] \\
Y && Z \arrow[ll]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This syntax `\arrow[ur, "f"]` etc is a pain to type in TeXShop, since TeXShop is configured to produce smart TeX quotes `\``\` `''` rather than the straight up-down doouble quotes required by the tikz sytax.

Comment: @murray Never use smart quotes. They aren't *really* smart.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, with wee bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
                & Y \\
X \urar["f"]
  \drar["f" ']  &   \\
                & Z \ar[uu]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that shorter form of syntax for arrows. Quicker to type; harder to read! But a pain to type in TeXShop when the latter is configured, as I have it, to produce smart TeX-aware quote pairs `\`\`` ...`''` instead of the straight up-down double-quotes that tikz requires there.